# Guidance on best practice: Posting to server to fetch SQL query data and redirect user back to UI with data

Tags: sql-server, node.js, ajax, post, express-4

Hello I am needing some assistance with a current project I am working on. The goal is to be able to interact with SQL from the UI and display the returned data in a table.

I am using node V9.8.0, express 4.16.3 and mssql 4.1.0.

I am able to connect and fetch data and display it on the UI but I do not think my set up is best practice.

My main road block was figuring out how to send information to the server to than query SQL and redirect the user back to the UI with the table displayed with the expected data.

Front end set up, form and ajax. I know that the action in the form should match the URL for ajax but to get this to work I have two post routes on the sever side. The form submits to the first post route and writes the req.body to a file. The ajax post URL reads the file and than connects to SQL and knows what data to fetch based on the user's input and predefined query strings that can take in parameters.

```
 <form id="myForm" action="/qa-hub/tools/wss_qa_tool/sql/data" method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select type="text" id="slct1" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xf002; SQL query search..." 
                                    name="query" list="query">
                                        <option value="">Query select...</option>
                                        <option value="vacant_units">vacant_units</option>
                                        <option value="cancelable_contracts">cancelable_contracts</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="slct2" style="display: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Entity #" name="location" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="slct3" style="display: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit #" name="unit" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button value="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 25%; font-size: 14pt">Submit</button>
                        </form>

<script>

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/qa-hub/tools/wss_qa_tool/api/data",
        dataType: "json"
        }).then(addData)
                function addData(data) {
                // console.log(Object.keys(data.recordset[0]));
                Object.keys(data.recordset[0]).forEach(function(column) {
                    $("#theadRow").append("<th>" + column + "</th>");
                });

                let master = "";

                for(var i = 0; i < data.recordset.length; i++) {
                for( var key in data.recordset[i]) {
                    var current = "<td>" + data.recordset[i][key] + "</td>";
                        master = master + current;

                }
                $("#tBody").append("<tr>" + master + "</tr>");
                master = "";
                }
                $('#myTable').DataTable()
            }
</script>
```

This is my set up on the server side. So this will take in the req.body from the form and write it to a file, than redirect the user back.

```
router.post("/sql/data", (req, res) => {
    let query = req.body.query;
    let sent_params = queries[query].params;
        let sentArr = sent_params.map( x => req.body.hasOwnProperty(x));
        // console.log(sentArr);
        if(sentArr.includes(false) ) {
            console.log("Missing parameter");
            res.redirect("/qa-hub/tools/wss_qa_tool");
        } else {
            let tempObj = {};
            for(var i = 0; i < sent_params.length; i++) {
                tempObj[sent_params[i]] = req.body[sent_params[i]];
            }
            tempObj["query"] = query;
            let sentObj = tempObj;


        let userId = req.user.id;

        fs.writeFile(`./temp/${userId}.json`, JSON.stringify(sentObj), (error) => {
            if(error) console.log(error);
            res.redirect("back");
        });
    }
});
```

This is where the magic happens. This post route will than read the file and pass in the information to saved SQL queries that can take in parameters and than sends the information back to the UI.

```
router.post("/api/data", (req, res, next) => {
    let userId = req.user.id;
    fs.readFile(`./temp/${userId}.json`, "utf-8", (err, info) => {
        if(info === undefined || info === "" || Object.keys(JSON.parse(info)).length === 0 ) {
            console.log("No data was found.");
        } else {
            let data = JSON.parse(info);
            let query = data.query;
            let location = data.location;
            let unit = data.unit;
            let selected_query = queries[query].arguments([location, unit]);

            var config = {
            user: 'xxxx',
            password: 'xxxx',
            server: 'xxxx', 
            database: 'xxxx'
            };

            sql.connect(config, function (err) {

                if (err) console.log("Error at the config.");

                console.log("Connected!");

                // create Request object
                var request = new sql.Request();

                // query to the database and get the records
                request.query( selected_query, function (err, queryData) {

                    if (err) console.log("There was an error")
                    // console.log(queryData);
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(queryData));
                    sql.close();
                    console.log("SQL connection closed.")
                    fs.unlink(`./temp/${userId}.json`, (err) => {
                        if(err) console.log(err);
                        console.log("File was deleted successfully!");
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

To me this seems like a hackish set up but I needed to produce results sooner than later. What I could not figure out or find was how can I produce the same set up with maybe one post route? I could not wrap my head around how to send information to the server, SQL query to fetch data and than redirect the data and  user back to the same page. Wondering what the best practice would be for this type of set up? Or possibly any insightful reading to help guide me? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: TLDR, why you write a file instead of returining a JSON ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  I had to Google TLDR.... I used to be cool...   :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza what is the point of me posting all of my details if your not even going to read it.......and why even bother commenting...The reason for the length of my question is to try and mitigate the guess work of what im trying to accomplish and in hopes to get a helpful response sooner.

Comment: The problem is you wrote too many details but don't explain what is the problem you try to solve until the end. So I lost interest midway. Still not sure what is the problem yet. I have done those multiple time and is very easy to setup. But I wont spend 20 minutes trying to understand your code.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza in that case i'm hoping you can help. I'll meet you half way and answer you question. The reason I write to a file is to temporally store the passed in data from the req.body. The second post route reads the file and than passes that data into the query strings params too than perform a res.send. Ajax than listens for this post route and renders the returned query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza so I get how to send JSON but I need to send the object along with redirecting the user back to the same page. If I just do res.send it just sends the data....See where im stuck?

Comment: Why you need redirect? why not update the element on the same page? that is what ajax does. Again I fail to see the problem. Im more of a visual person maybe add some picture or a diagram explaining what is happening now and what is your desire behaviour.

Comment: That is where im getting stuck. Maybe you can help this way. What if I just have a route that performs a res.send(JSON.stringify(data);. How can I render that data on the UI? Typically I would have a post route and a get route. The post would store the information to my DB and I would use a get route to render the object onto the UI with EJS. But the road block for me is this is a query so the data is dynamic based on what the user submits in the form to the server.